# How to calculate coefficients for double integrals

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

So this is a general question about double integrals, triple integrals etc.

The question was given a lens defined in cylindrical coordnates:
$$0 < \theta < 2\pi$$
$$r^2 + z^2 < 2$$
$$z > 1$$

to calculate the surface area of the curved surface.

This is what I tried (its incorrect somewhere I believe it is in the calculation area bit rather than the abstractions I choose)

I tried doing this via converting it into spherical coordnates because the $r^2 + z^2 <2$ will define circle about the origin.

Hence the lens can be defined:
$$0< \theta < 2\pi$$
$$r = \sqrt2$$
$$\frac{\pi}{4} < \phi < \frac{\pi}{2}$$

[note that the theta is the same as before]

[possible error]

So the squares over which I am summing have area $rd\theta*rd\phi$

Hence the surface area is:

$$\int_\phi\int_\theta r^2 d\theta d\phi$$

So where I think I am incorrect is in the infinitesimal area that I am summing.

But is this approach to figuring out the coefficients of the $d\theta d\phi$ correct in the general case?

Comment: You are missing a factor of $\sin{\phi}$, this comes from the Jacobian of transformation. Also your limits for $\phi$ are not correct.

Comment: @Triatticus why does it need the factor of $\sin \phi$

Comment: It comes from calculating the magnitude of the cross product of the tangent vectors to the surface for the parametric equations of a surface in spherical coordinates